# Creating bar Chart for csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I am having a csv file which contains data like below

```
Host                     % Time OK  
test1.abc.data.com     99.989% (99.989%)    
test2.abc.data.com  100.000% (100.000%)
test3.abc.data.com  100.000% (100.000%)
```

Need to generate bar chart in the same csv using this data.

Requesting some ideas how to do this

Comment: a bar chart WHERE? [*grin*] spreadsheet? text file? console window? ... it makes a difference ...

Comment: Sorry..updated the question. Need to generate in the same csv

Comment: not a problem ... now, how do you intend to put a CHART in a CSV file? that is almost certainly not going to be valid unless you want to add a column with a text string to represent the chart info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/6.5.1) PowerShell module to create charts in Excel file

example:

```
Get-Process | Export-Excel c:\temp\test.xlsx -WorkSheetname Processes -ChartType PieExploded3D -IncludePivotChart -IncludePivotTable -Show -PivotRows Company -PivotData PM
```

If you want to have image file with chart, below link will help you

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/richard_macdonald/2009/04/28/charting-with-powershell/